# Open a url, in jquery php

Tags: php, jquery

when I click on "Click Here" then a page must open inside

```
<script....>
$('yahoo').html('<a href=desc.php>');
</script>

<div id='yahoo'></div>
<div id='clickhere'>Click here</div>
```

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for AJAX to fetch the page for you. Something like this might work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#clickhere').click(function() {
            $('#yahoo').load('desc.php');
        });
    });
</script>

<div id='yahoo'></div>
<div id='clickhere'>Click here</div>
```

First you need to wrap the script inside `$(function() { ... })` to execute your code on page load. This is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`.

Next you have to bind a click event to the `#clickhere` element so you can actually do something when the user clicks on it.

When the user clicks on the `#clickhere` div, [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) will fetch the contents of the given url inside the element you call it from. So, this snippet means that when the `#clickhere` div is clicked, `desc.php` is loaded inside `#yahoo` div.

Answer (score 3):

1. ID selector is `#ID`, not just `ID`
2. Use [jQuery AJAX load method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load `desc.php` page
3. You should execute your jQuery code after `DOMContentLoaded` event

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function() { });`, which will insure that the code executes after the DOM is available to your code.  Otherwise, `$('yahoo')` will likely return no matched elements.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try target_self ? I also fixed some code

```
<script....>
$('yahoo').html('<a href=desc.php target='>self'>Click here</a>');
</script>

<div id='yahoo'></div>
<div id='clickhere'>Click here</div>
```